# why a asynctask is executed once even if ,i close aplication?

Tags: android, task, execute

i have a asynctask to check access internet, but sometimes it does not run, So i would appreciate if explain me this weird behavior.

this is my code:

```
 if(activeNetworkinfo.getType()==ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI){
                        if(NetworkPrivider()){

                        //this is my asyntask with weird behavior,and always enter here.

                            CheckInternetAccess   ch=new CheckInternetAccess();
                            ch.execute();
                            Log.i("sms", "Esta conetado a wifi");
                        }else{
                            mycallback.QuePaso(MainActivity.LOCALIZACION_APAGADA_WIFI);
                        }

                    }if(activeNetworkinfo.getType()==ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE){
                    Log.i("sms", "Esta conetado a datos");
                        if(GpsON()){
                            CheckInternetAccess  ch=new CheckInternetAccess();
                            ch.execute();
                        }else{
                            mycallback.QuePaso(MainActivity.LOCALIZACION_APAGADA_GPS);
                        }

                    }
```

and this is my asyntask :

```
     public class CheckInternetAccess extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        //http://clients3.google.com/generate_204
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Log.i("sms", "Checando acceso a internet...");
            try {
                HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection)
                        (new URL("http://clients3.google.com/generate_204")
                                .openConnection());
                urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Android");
                urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
                urlc.setConnectTimeout(1000);
                urlc.connect();
                return (urlc.getResponseCode() == 204 && urlc.getContentLength() == 0);
            }catch (SocketTimeoutException ex){
                Log.e("ChecarInternet: ", "Error esperando", ex);

                cancel(true);
            }catch (ConnectException e) {
                Log.e("ChecarInternet: ", "Sin acceso a internet", e);
                cancel(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("ChecarInternet: ", "Error checking internet connection", e);
                cancel(true);
            }
            return false;
        }
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

if(result){
//do someting.
}
}
}
```

when i install aplication the asyntask is executed, but if i close the aplication and i open again already not execute the asynctask until that ,I delete application data or install again.
sometimes it is executed normally.

Comment: Is this in your onCreate method? when you say close, do you mean you kill the app or is it just off screen? you may want to call this in onResume().

Comment: in oncreate method call a class and this class has the asyntask and a interface that i implement in activitymain ,so when asyntask  result is  true, execute a calback toward my mainactivity in the line "//do someting." and when i close apliction i mean to destroy completely.

and i'm sorry for my english but i'm from mexico..

Answer (score 0):

Use this way,

```
class MyActivity {
    CheckInternetAccess ch;

    void someMethod() {
        ch = new CheckInternetAccess();
        ch.execute();
    }

    void onPause() { // Activitys onPause
        if (ch != null) {
            ch.cancel(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but my asynctask it is not in activity ,my asynctask it's on simple class, do you think that works also?

Comment: yes. then find which application is using this asynctask. and cancel where needed.

Comment: So what it's difference between ch.cancel(); and cancel(true);  , because i am cancelling when occurred an exception error

Comment: it will be cancel true. if no error occurs it still running. post your full code from activity.

Comment: i already resolved the issue ,my asynctask always was working, the problem was that the doinbackground is called after a long delay, So i found this, executeOnExecutor and works well. but thank you very much Sazzad Hossain Khan for taking the time to help me.